# Cannot instantiate class inside a test-jar

Tags: maven, cmd, testng

I have a project that only consists of test classes which all extend from one abstract base class. The tests run fine in intellij, and when running mvn clean install with the correct profile specified.

What I want to do is create a test jar and run the tests from command-line, so i'm using these commands:

```
mvn -DoutputDirectory=target -f pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This first command is getting all the dependencies and putting them along side the test jar that is created in the target folder.

```
java -cp .;target/* org.testng.TestNG -testjar target/my-test-jar.jar -xmlpathinjar sanity.xml
```

I get this:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot instantiate class com.myPackage.MyTestClass
```

The class is definitely there, and I can run sanity.xml from inside intellij.

The weirdest bit is that I can delete the java file from my project, and then put this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    args = new String[4]
    args[0] = "-testjar"
    args[1] = "target/my-test-jar.jar"
    args[2] = "-xmlpathinjar"
    args[3] = "sanity.xml"
    org.testng.TestNG.main(args)
}
```

Inside another Test class of my project, and it will manage to instantiate MyTestClass from inside the jar file.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? I don't get any stack trace or log files, just the simple fact that it cannot instantiate the class. I'm hoping someone has come across this before and knows how to solve it.

Cheers,
David

[EDIT - Adding part of the pom file]

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>buildOnly</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-resource</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                                        <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                                <sources>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integrationTest</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                                    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-resource</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                                        <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                                <sources>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${testng.xml.file}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter,org.testng.reporters.JUnitXMLReporter,org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter,org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter,org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter,org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>isCI</name>
                                <value>${isCI}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>browser</name>
                                <value>${browser}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>remote</name>
                                <value>${remote}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>port</name>
                                <value>${port}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>environment</name>
                                <value>${environment}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>subDomain</name>
                                <value>${subDomain}</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Can you show the pom file of this project?

Comment: Not all of it, I can show the profiles and plugins section. I'll edit my post and put it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you tests are correctly located into [src/test/java](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and correctly named based on the [unit test naming conventions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) than your tests can simply be run from command line via

```
mvn test
```

but it looks your tests are named different which will cause your problems.

Comment: The tests can already be run from command line with mvn test. The issue is that I want to run the tests from a test jar that has been built by maven.

Comment: Why? Are you talking about unit tests or integration tests? Furthermore after taking a look into your poms your integration tests should be handled by the maven-failsafe-plugin instead of maven-surefire-plugin. Added in src/test/resources via build-helper-plugin is not needed, cause it's default in Maven. An a skipTest is very bad.

Comment: That way we can have a jar in the repository that can be pulled down and run on any jenkins machine with access to the repository, without said machine needing access to our source control or the person setting up the job needing remote access to the jenkins machine.

The tests are integration tests, it doesn't make much sense to run them when the jar is being created, although they can be with the -P integrationTest profile.

Thanks for pointing out the unnecessary src/test/resources line.

The surefire plugin isn't used when executing from a jar (I don't think).

Comment: If these tests are integration tests they should be configured in the right way with Maven using the maven-failsafe-plugin. And usually better a separate module in maven to make particular setups simpler in maven.

Answer (score 0):

The message says "Can't instantiate", not "Can't find".

TestNG can find your class but can't instantiate it. The first piece of information to supply in your question would be the source of `MyTestClass`, but even without that, I'm guessing you didn't define a simple parameterless constructor:

```
public MyTestClass() {}
```